# Building a specific type of a package

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I am new to Gradle. Here is my scenario. I have a Gradle project. This project doesn’t have any java code. All it has, is a ‘build.gradle’ file … to package other war/jar/libs/configs from certain source directories, and create a TAR.GZ file output. … This ‘build.gradle’ file is currently being used, before implementing DevOps.

Now, after implementing DevOps, we use Artifactory repository to store all war/jar/libs/configs files.

We want to update this ‘build.gradle’ file to fetch / download all the files from Artifactory … to build the TAR package ... rather sourcing it from local directories.

I have a specific need:

•   Produce 3 different package types – LIGHT / PARTIAL / FULL … meaning, LIGHT package will have a pre-defined set of files, PARTIAL package will have custom selection, FULL package will have everything
•   I want to pass the option, via the gradle.properties file
•   Gradle should download the files from Artifactory, according to the package type mentioned in the properties file (LIGHT/PARTIAL/FULL)
•   Is it possible to bring in such dynamism into a build.gradle file?

Please guide. THANKS A LOT

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [file specs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+File+Specs) to download files from Artifactory for your different packages. For example you can have different file specs for the different package types you mentioned and download them using the [REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API) or the [JFrog CLI](https://jfrog.com/getcli). These file specs can be used in your Gradle builds.

You can find a few sample specs on [GitHub](https://github.com/jfrogtraining/demoscripts/tree/master/cliwebinar)